# Include Bootstrap form css alone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have site created already which is not bootstrap, and now i need to implement the bootstrapValidator for the validation purpose, if i include bootstrap css then my site style also changing,

Is there any way to include bootstrap form styles alone in html, apart from cut copy in bootstrap css file?

Comment: I am curious why you chose BootstrapValidator for a non-Bootstrap site in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
and check only the "form" checkbox to download only the part you need...

Answer (score 1):

Use customize css download from [bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), here you see the options of customizations. You can choose what you want in your CSS. Or you can use less css, download the bootstrap less master from github and compile theme as per your project needs.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to find a stylesheet that someone else took the time to copy / paste from the Bootstrap. I've done this on several occasions, and its pretty simple as all the form-styling elements are placed next to each other in the bootstrap stylesheet.

So, find you scissors :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a part of a css file, so you can copy/paste your desires classes on your actual css or rename your classes in your css file to not have conflicts with bootstrap's classes name and then your site's style will not change when you include bootstrap.